# javascript scope and everything about 'this'

Tags: callback, closures, this, bind, arrow-functions

I am trying to understand in depth how '*this*' works in javascript.
All I have known about *this* so far is,

1. Every function has properties and whenever the function executes, it newly defines the *this* property.
2. *this* refers to the object that a function is invoked to (including window object in browser).
3. *this* refers to the scope of the object(where the object is defined) instead of referring to the object itself if you use arrow syntax when defining a function because arrow function does not newly defines its own *this*.

The examples below are to help understanding the behaviour of *this*

```js
class Example {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'John';
  }

  method1() { //case1 : Closure
    console.log(this.name);

    function method2() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }

    method2();
  }
}

const a = new Example()
a.method1();
```

---

```js
function testing(callback) {
  return callback();
}

class Example2 {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'John';
  }

  method1() { //case2: callback
    console.log(this.name);

    testing(function() {
      console.log(this.name);
    })
  }
}

const b = new Example2()
b.method1();
```

---

```js
function testing(callback) {
  return callback();
}

class Example3 {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'John';
  }

  method1() { //case3: arrow syntax callback
    console.log(this.name);

    testing(() => {
      console.log(this.name);
    })
  }
}

const c = new Example3()
c.method1(); // logs 'John'
// logs 'John'
```

---

```js
function testing(callback) {
  return callback();
}

class Example4 {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'John';
  }

  method1() { // case4: calling method as callback
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  render() {
    testing(this.method1)

  }
}

const d = new Example4()
d.render()
```

---

```js
function testing(callback) {
  return callback();
}

class Example5 {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'John';
    this.method1 = this.method1.bind(this);
  }

  method1() { //case5: bind method && calling method as callback 
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  render() {
    testing(this.method1)

  }
}

const d = new Example5()
d.render()
```

I wonder how those above cases are different and what the *this* refers to inside each inner function and callback. Could you please explain about it? thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @jonsilver he doesn't ask "how", he asks "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the in-depth precise explanation can be pretty big and boring, here is an [exceptional article by kangax](http://perfectionkills.com/know-thy-reference/) that perfectly lays it out.

And just in case, if you need a short and ultra condensed version of it here goes my short and approximate take:

## #

When you call a function the `this` is determined by the specific `base value` which is usually pointing to whatever is on the left of the `.`
in `MemberExpression` so in `x.y()` `this === x`, and in `x.y.z()` `this === x.y`.

In case of a simple `CallExpression` without the `.`, say just `x()`,
the base value is implicitly inferred to point to `undefined`, which in non-strict mode is converted to global `window` and in strict mode stays the same.

This is the general mental model which should cover 99% of all the day-to-day problems with drawing the `this` context out correctly.

Now on, to the actual cases:

**CASE 1:**

`a.method1();` call has a base value `a` so the `this` inside of its body points to `a`, so no surprises here.
`method2` has implicit base value `undefined.method2`, thus you have the `TypeError` which explicitly states that.

**CASE 2:**

```
function testing(callback) {
  return callback();
}
```

`callback()` is called with implicit baseValue `undefined`, i.e. `undefined.callback()`,
and since the passed function is declared within `class`

```
testing(function() {
  console.log(this.name);
})
```

that triggers the strict mode of code execution, that's why `undefined` is not converted again to global `window`, thus we have the same error as before.

**CASE 3:**

Arrow function

```
testing(() => {
   console.log(this.name);
})
```

creates a hard binding from the `this` in enclosing scope,
basically under the hood it's the same as writing:

```
var _this = this;
testing((function() {
   console.log(_this.name);
});
```

That's why you get the same object resolved as `this`

**CASE 4:**

Alright, this one is interesting and needs more mechanics explanation.

So when you pass `this.method` in:

```
render() {
  testing(this.method1)
}
```

- what you actually pass is not the reference `this.method`, but the actual underlying Function Object value, to which this reference points to, so
  when it gets executed it has its this always pointing to `undefined`, [here  look](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation), so it's pretty much "in stone".

And yes of course since `this.method1` is declared in strict context again, thanks to enclosing es6 `class`, `undefined` remains `undefined` without conversion to global `window`.

**CASE 5:**

Same mechanics as with arrow function. Bind creates a wrapper function, which holds the cached `this` value, which is not possible to override with `.call` and `.apply`, the same as in `=>` function.

Hope this clarifies a bit it all a bit.